# Composite query

Tags: mysql

Table with following columns:

```
Player_id (primary key), Event_type(A,B,C), Points.
```

1 player may appear many times for every event_type

I would like to show an overall ranking with DESC SUM(Points) GROUP BY player_id from all event-type while putting some conditions:

- only best 5 results per player_id for event type A
- only best 2 results per player_id for event type B
- only best 3 results per player_id for event type C

I have tried in vain :

```
SUM(points) WHERE event_type ="X" 
GROUP BY Player_id ORDER BY SUM(points) LIMIT N
```

Ive been fighting this headache for a week now, pretty confused when it comes to include sub-queries, UNION, or temp tables. I cant figure out how to put all the pieces together...

My dream would be to get this overall ranking running with the ability to access detailed points breakdown per player upon click....

Open to any kind of help on this one...thanks!

Example of the source table :

**player_id------event_type-------score-----**

---1-------------------A----------------**5**----------

---1-------------------A---------------**10**---------

---1-------------------A----------------**5**---------

---1-------------------A----------------5---------

---1-------------------A----------------2---------

---1-------------------A----------------**15**---------

---1-------------------A----------------**10**---------

---1-------------------C----------------20---------

---1-------------------B----------------**5**---------

---1-------------------B----------------5---------

---1-------------------B----------------**20**---------

---2-------------------A----------------**50**---------

---2-------------------B----------------**55**---------

Desired output according to this example:

**Rank---player_id-------overall_score-----**

----1----------2-----------**105 POINTS** [50 from A(best 5) + 55 from B (best 2)]---------

----2----------1-----------**90 POINTS** [45 from A(best 5) + 20 from C (best3) + 25 from B (best 2)]---------

Comment: Can you provide an example of the current data and your expected result in a tabular format? That would help a lot.

Comment: I've just added a simplified example with the desired output. Thanks Mosty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: The features you desire are called `sliding window` and `ranking`. Oracle implements these with the `OVER`-keyword and the `rank()`-function. MySQL does not support these features, so we have to work around this.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692041/top-n-results-for-each-keyword) to create the following query. Give him a `+1` too, if this is helpful to you.

```
SELECT 
    `player_id`, `event`, `points`,
    (SELECT 1 + count(*) 
     FROM `points` 
     WHERE `l`.`player_id` = `player_id` 
         AND `l`.`event` = `event` 
         AND `points` > `l`.`points`
    ) AS `rank`
FROM
    `points` `l`
```

This will output for every `player_id` and `event` the rank of the `points`. For example:
Assuming `(player_id, event, points)` has `(1,A,10), (1,A,5), (1,A,2), (1,A,2), (1,A,1), (2,A,0)` then the output would be

```
player_id    event   points   rank
  1            A       10       1
  1            A        5       2
  1            A        2       3
  1            A        2       3
  1            A        1       5
  2            A        0       1
```

The rank is not dense, so if you have duplicate tuples, you will have output tuples with the same rank as well as gaps in your rank number.

To get the top `N`* tuples for each `player_id` and `event` you could either create a view or use the subquery in the condition. The view is the preferred way, but you don't have the priviledge to create views on many servers.

**Creating a view that contains the `rank` as column.**

```
CREATE VIEW `points_view`
AS SELECT 
    `player_id`, `event`, `points`,
    (SELECT 1 + count(*) 
         FROM `points` 
         WHERE `l`.`player_id` = `player_id` 
             AND `l`.`event` = `event` 
             AND `points` > `l`.`points`
        ) as `rank`
FROM
    `points` `l`
```

Get the desired top N results from the view:

```
SELECT
    `player_id`, `event`, `points`
FROM `points_view`
WHERE 
     `event` = 'A' AND `rank` <= 5
OR
     `event` = 'B' AND `rank` <= 2
OR
     `event` = 'C' AND `rank` <= 3
```

**Using the rank in the condition**

```
SELECT 
    `player_id`, `event`, `points`
FROM
    `points` `l`
WHERE
    (SELECT 1 + count(*) 
     FROM `points` 
     WHERE `l`.`player_id` = `player_id` 
         AND `l`.`event` = `event` 
         AND `points` > `l`.`points`
    ) <= N
```

To further get a different amount of tuples depending on your event, you could do

```
SELECT 
    `player_id`, `event`, `points`
FROM
    `points` `l`
WHERE
        `event` = 'A' AND
        (SELECT 1 + count(*) 
         FROM `points` 
         WHERE `l`.`player_id` = `player_id` 
             AND `l`.`event` = `event` 
             AND `points` > `l`.`points`
        ) <= 5
    OR
        `event` = 'B' AND
        (SELECT 1 + count(*) 
         FROM `points` 
         WHERE `l`.`player_id` = `player_id` 
             AND `l`.`event` = `event` 
             AND `points` > `l`.`points`
        ) <= 2
    OR
        `event` = 'C' AND
        (SELECT 1 + count(*) 
         FROM `points` 
         WHERE `l`.`player_id` = `player_id` 
             AND `l`.`event` = `event` 
             AND `points` > `l`.`points`
        ) <= 3
```

I would just use the maximum of your `N`'s which is 5 and ignore the other tuples for the other event-types as MySQL does not optimize this query which results in 3 separate dependent subqueries. If performance is not an issue or you don't have much data anyways, keep it that way.

* As I explained the `rank` is not dense, so getting all tuples with `rank <= N` will generally result in more than `N` tuples. The additional tuples are duplicates.

Simply removing duplicates is a bad idea as you can see from the example table. If you wanted the top 5 results for `player_id = 1` and `event = A`, you would need both tuples `(1,A,2)`. They both have rank 3. But if you remove one of them, you will only end up with the top 4 results `(1,A,10,1)`, `(1,A,5,2)`, `(1,A,2,3)`, `(1,A,1,5)`.

To get a dense rank you could use this subquery

```
(SELECT count(DISTINCT `points`) 
 FROM `points` 
 WHERE `l`.`player_id` = `player_id` 
     AND `l`.`event` = `event` 
     AND `points` >= `l`.`points`
) as `dense_rank`
```

Be careful as this will still produce duplicate ranks.

**Edit**

To sum all event's points to one score, use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
    `player_id`, SUM(`points`)
FROM `points_view`
WHERE 
     `event` = 'A' AND `rank` <= 5
OR
     `event` = 'B' AND `rank` <= 2
OR
     `event` = 'C' AND `rank` <= 3

GROUP BY `player_id`
ORDER BY SUM(`points`) DESC
```

Before the partitioning (`GROUP BY`) the result contains the correct amount of top-scores so you can simply sum all points together.

The big problem you are facing here is that neither `rank` nor `dense_rank` will give you the tool get exactly 5 tuples for each `player_id` and `event`. For example: If someone got 1000 times 1 point for event A, he will end up with 1000 points as all points will get `rank` and `dense_rank` `1`.

There is the `ROWNUM` but again: MySQL does not support this, so we have to emulate this. The problem with `ROWNUM` is that it will generate a composite numer for all tuples. But we want composite numbers for groups of `player_id`, `event`. I'm still working on this solution though.

**Edit2**

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332131/1220835) I found this solution to work:

```
select
  player_id, sum( points )
from
(
select
  player_id,
  event,
  points,
  /* increment current_pos and reset to 0 if player_id or event changes */
  @current_pos := if (@current_player = player_id AND 
      @current_event = event, @current_pos, 0) + 1 as position,
  @current_player := player_id,
  @current_event := event
from
  (select 
    /* global variable init */
    @current_player := null, 
    @current_event := null, 
    @current_pos := 0) set_pos,
  points
order by
  player_id,
  event,
  points desc
) pos
WHERE
     pos.event = 'A' AND pos.position <= 5
OR
     pos.event = 'B' AND pos.position <= 2
OR
     pos.event = 'C' AND pos.position <= 3
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY SUM( points ) DESC
```

The inner query selects (player_id, event, points)-tuples, sorts them by player_id and event and finally gives each tuple a composite number which is reset to 0 every time either player_id or event changes. Because of the order all tuples with the same player_id will be consecutive. the outer query does the same as the previously used query does with the view.

**Edit3** (see comments)

You can create intermediate sums, or different kind of partitions with OLAPs ROLLUP-operator. The query would for example look like this:

```
select
  player_id, event, sum( points )
from
(
select
  player_id,
  event,
  points,
  /* increment current_pos and reset to 0 if player_id or event changes */
  @current_pos := if (@current_player = player_id AND 
      @current_event = event, @current_pos, 0) + 1 as position,
  @current_player := player_id,
  @current_event := event
from
  (select 
    /* global variable init */
    @current_player := null, 
    @current_event := null, 
    @current_pos := 0) set_pos,
  points
order by
  player_id,
  event,
  points desc
) pos
WHERE
     pos.event = 'A' AND pos.position <= 5
OR
     pos.event = 'B' AND pos.position <= 2
OR
     pos.event = 'C' AND pos.position <= 3
GROUP BY player_id, event WITH ROLLUP
/* NO ORDER BY HERE. SEE DOCUMENTATION ON MYSQL's ROLLUP FOR REASON */
```

The result will now first be grouped by `player_id, event`, then by only `player_id` and lastly by null (summing up all rows).

The first groups look like `(player_id, event, sum(points)) = {(1, A, 20), (1,B,5)}` where 20 and 5 are the sum of the points regarding `player_id` and `event`. The second groups look like `(player_id, event, sum(points)) = {(1,NULL,25)}`. 25 is the sum of all points regarding the `player_id`. Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Basti for the effort. I will give it a go tonight after work and get back to you with some feedback. I've also added a simplified example with the targeted result to the initial question.

Comment: Just for clarification: The overall-score should be just the bold number? The other numbers are just to explain?

Comment: Bold numbers are there just to highlight the top N scores per player per event, i.e, overall score by player should be the sum of all those bold numbers. other numbers are there on the source table but are not supposed to be considered for the overall score since they are out of the top N scores per event type. I am trying your approach right now.

Comment: As for the duplicates tuples, I hope we can find a solution using ROWNUM which sounds like a once for all solution. Could we use other columns from the source table to split them apart in case of ties? extra columns in my case could be 'event_standing', 'event_rating' among others...

Comment: One more thing, I've tried to +1 the answer but couldn't, it seems I need 15 rep points to +1 here :)

Comment: ALL CONFIRMED AS EXPECTED! that worked nicely (used subquery instead of creating a view) . However some duplicate scores have been added to the overall score...Ive tried to add 2 decimals to 'points' to narrow down probability of ties, still got couple of similar scores. ANSWER ACCEPTED even though I have to get around the duplicate scores (ROWNUM, using extra columns to sort further...?). Then next step would be to link overall score detail breakdown for every player upon click. Can't wait for your feedback. Thanks a mill.

Comment: Hi Basti, any news regarding duplicate top scores?

Comment: Last query added should work. There are no gaps in this query so your points should be calculated correclty.

Comment: This approach works perfectly. Thanks a bunch! I just need to show the details for every player now so people can understand where the overall score is coming from. The ideal would be to show it upon click on the player_id or maybe just display another column with the different countable events with score in a single row. Maybe should I ask this as new question...

Comment: Added another example using the `ROLLUP`-operator.

Comment: Thanks once again Basti. This does the trick for showing details for every player per event. However it seems I can't display the overall ranking which is ordered descendent by SUM(points) along with ROLLUP at the same time. I guess I have to display 2 queries separatly, one for the overall ranking and another one for details upon request from the user.

Comment: Yes you are not allowed to use `ORDER BY` and `ROLLUP` together in mysql. I can imagine why, but it's a shame.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to give the sum(points) a name.

So do:

```
select player,sum(points) as points from table where event_type = "x" group by player order by points desc limit 5;
```

(I'd need to see your exact table schema to write this as something you can just drop in, but this is the gist of it)

Comment: There is no need to give every output column an alias. `sum(points)` is a perfectly fine name for the column. The query in the question is syntactically correct, but just does not produce the desired output.